# Excluding Files and Folders from dupFinder

Tags: resharper, dupfinder

I'm trying to use dupFinder to scan for duplications in a .NET codebase. I have certain files and folders that I want to exclude from the scan but I'm struggling to get it working.

The command I'm running is:

```
dupfinder.exe --show-text --output="dupReport.xml" --exclude="Some.Folder.*;*Resource.designer.cs"  MyCode.sln
```

So what I'm trying to do is:

Scan the `MyCode.sln` solution.

Ignore all folders matching the pattern `Some.Folder.*` e.g. `Some.Folder.Code` and `Some.Folder.Tests` (these folders are in the root of the repository alongside the solution file).

Ignore all files matching the pattern `*Resource.designer.cs` in any folder i.e. `MyCode.Resource.designer.cs`.

I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong but the dupFinder documentation doesn't show an example of using the exclude option.

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually managed to get this working, the conclusion I've drawn is that you can't exclude folders only files.

I think because my original exclude pattern was trying to ignore folders the whole thing wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I also searched for this.

To exclude complete folders you should use double *

e.g.

```
--exclude="**\Tests\**;**\Resource.designer.cs"
```

excludes all Files in all Tests folders and Resource.designer.cs in whatever folder.

Edit:
Tested and still working on JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2020.3.4. Which was the current version when I wrote the answer.
Current version seems to have a bug again and not excluding at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I haven't been able to figure out how the exclude is supposed to work as nothing that I give it seems to affect the output.

Comment: @MBentley are you working on Windows? Otherwise you'ld need to use / instead of \
This:
dupfinder.exe --exclude="\**\NewFolder2\\*\*" UnitTestProject1.sln
Works fine for me.

Comment: @ Starbax yes it is Windows. The command `dupfinder.exe --exclude="**\Migrations\**" foo.sln` said that it was "excluding: **\Migrations\**", but the output includes 242 instances of "\Migrations\", such as <FileName>..\Submodules\DatabaseLibrary\Migrations\20210603145922_DescFoo.Designer.cs</FileName>

Comment: @MBentley did you try to exclude the path \*\*\ Submodules\DatabaseLibrary\Migrations\\*\* ? The front wildcard may not work as I expected, not sure if my Tests folder was a subfolder or not.

Comment: yes I tried that. I even tried just --exclude="**\Submodules\**". No matter what I put in, I seem to get the exact same file. I have yet to see any sign that this tool can do even basic filtering. Unfortunate, because it is a neat idea, but without filtering it is not really usable for me.

Comment: I found a link where JetBrains says that this issue is currently shelved. It looks like they admit that it doesn't work, haven't even fixed the documentation, and have no intention of fixing it. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468092

Comment: hm.. well. I Tried JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2020.2.5 again and this works fine. Maybe this was fixed and unfixed again^^

Comment: @MBentley this version can be found here: jetbrains.com/resharper/download/other.html pls upvote again. Thx

Comment: @MBentley JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2020.3.4 is also working. seems to be only the current version which is not working again.

Comment: @MBentley did you try the other version?